# URL Rewrite - optional parameter?

Tags: regex, web-config, url-rewriting, optional-parameters

I would like a regex string to reflect an optional parameter, in this case, a geographic state.

I can accomplish this with two rules:

```
<rewrite url="~/(.+)-(.+)/(.+).aspx" to="~/Default.aspx?city=$1&amp;state=$2&amp;term=$3&amp;x=$4"/>
<rewrite url="~/(.+)/(.+).aspx" to="~/Default.aspx?city=$1&amp;state=NONE&amp;term=$2&amp;x=$4"/>
```

With, a query to /Los+Angeles/cars.aspx:
Geo - city: Los Angeles
Geo - state: NONE

With, a query to /Los+Angeles-CA/cars.aspx:
Geo - city: Los Angeles
Geo - state: CA

I'm curious about if there is a way to do this in one rewrite statement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have not messed with rewrite url in the config in a while but am quite used to regex. Would this work for you?

```
<rewrite url="~/([^-]+)(?:-(.+))?/(.+).aspx" to="~/Default.aspx?city=$1&amp;state=$2&amp;term=$3&amp;x=$4"/>
```

The state would not say none but should actually be blank.

Comment: That may work, I'll give it a whirl.  The "none" was merely for for display purposes.

Comment: That works works just fine, thank you.  Now instead of the optional dash, I would like to have an optional slash, thus: /Los+Angeles/CA/cars.aspx .   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you willing to pass a blank string instead of NONE to the state parameter? If so, your 1st rule could be rewritten like this:

```
~/(.+)-?(.+)/(.+).aspx
```

...and your 2nd could be deleted.

Comment: This Regex, cuts the last letter off of second parameter, combines the first and second, and outputs the last letter as the second parameter.